# Maven ignoring JRE keystore

Tags: java, maven, ssl, intellij-idea

I have a self-signed CA certificate installed on my JRE keystore. When I type `keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts|grep mycert` I can actually see that it is properly installed. However, when I run some functional tests through Maven, I get errors like the following one:

```
Certificate for doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: []; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for doesn't match any of the subject alternative names
```

My setup is OSX Sierra, JRE 8u151-oracle and maven 3.0.5, both installed through sdkman. The most strange thing is that the errors disappear when I run maven from IntelliJ. I've been doing some investigation and found that it uses a different maven launcher. Here are the generated commands:

```
# IntelliJ 
/Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u151-oracle/bin/java 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false 
-Dmaven.home=/Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/maven/3.0.5 
-Dclassworlds.conf=/Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/maven/3.0.5/bin/m2.conf 
-classpath /Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/maven/3.0.5/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar 
org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher 
test

# Maven
Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u151-oracle/bin/java 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false 
-Dmaven.home=/Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current
-Dclassworlds.conf=/Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin/m2.conf 
-classpath /Users/jdebenitocalzada/.sdkman/candidates/maven/current/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar 
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher 
test
```

As you can see, the only difference is that IntelliJ uses `org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher` vs `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher` used by Maven when running from the CLI.

My question is mainly why Maven is ignoring the keystore when running from command line, but also, why it is using a different runner when running from IntelliJ, and what's the difference between both runners.

NOTE: I'm almost sure that the difference in behavior is due to the use of a different runner, it has nothing to do with JDK versions, as it runs properly when I run the IntelliJ-generated command from CLI.

Comment: Is maven from command line using same JDK as maven from intellij? Try starting a new commandline and typing `which java`

Comment: @vikingsteve yeah, IntelliJ and Maven from command line are using the same JDK. As you can see in above commands, from command line it's pointing to `current` version, but it's just a symlink to the same 3.0.5 version pointed by IntelliJ command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems that the problem had something to be with the fact that I was using an alias for adding some options to mvn command. After moving those options to `MAVEN_OPTS` env var, it started working properly.